# Is 360 video editing the same as traditional video editing?

Tags: 360video

With the rise and price drop in 360 video I'm wondering what the format is. Looking at the [CENTR Camera](http://centrcam.com/#technology) doesn't even mention editing or file format. [Ricoh Theta](https://theta360.com/en/about/theta/) doesn't mention file format or serious editing but does say they offer their own software for some editing.

What file type do 360 degree cameras use? Can it be edited in regular video production suites like SpeedGrade, DaVinci Resolve, Premier, FinalCut, etc.. or do you need some special software?

Comment: Theta S records in MP4 (1920x1080, 16x9, 15.9 Mbps, 29.97fps) and the previous one in MOV (7.9Mbps, 14.98fps). Interesting related article about 360 in After Effects: http://rocketstock.com/blog/creating-360-video-effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually 360° videos became 360° only in realtime during playback. You can see it:

1. Go to to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3xOB-Bigc8) (youtube now supports 360° videos)
2. Now, using Chrome install [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-youtube-html5-pla/enmofgaijnbjpblfljopnpdogpldapoc) (it will disable HTML5 player)
3. Try to see video from the point one again.

You will see something like that:
[image: Video from Vi Hart channel]

That happens because Flash player don't know how to interpret 360° video and showing original state of it.

So, during editing your 360° video can be displayed as normal video with huge distortion. If you can handle that, than you can edit it in any program of your chose.

Good luck!

Comment: Exactly, the format of the video is just a standard video file, most 360 cameras I've seen seem to export in MP4 or AVI video. It's just a normal video file, with the data distorted based on equirectangular projection, the same projection we use to take the earth and put it on a flat map..

Comment: @D3_JMultiply or Shultc - thanks, so trimming and color correction and stuff should be fairly easy. Logo might be doable since its so small and could try distorting it in Photoshop or some tool for photographers (a few exist). But to add say a caption or lower thirds are there any tools that can convert AE to Equirectangular to be overlayed so then it looks correct when uploaded?

Comment: yes, just whatever you do do not crop the video in any form, add borders etc.